# why is my this.setState not updating the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

am I missing something? I'm using es6 style to add to an empty array in this.state, but nothing is getting pushed to state.

I should be getting two inside of the array, but after console.logging nothing is showing. and my screen is not rerendering, since coponentDidUpdate is not running.

```js
class HomeModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      specificList: []
    };
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.updateState();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("after update: ", this.state.specificList);
  }

  updateState = () => {
    this.props.completeList.forEach(index => {
      index.list.forEach(innerArr => {
        if (innerArr.muscleGroup === this.props.selectedBodyPart) {
          console.log("test: ", innerArr);
          this.setState({
            specificList: [...this.state.specificList, innerArr.title]
          });
        }
      });
      console.log("after each loop: ", this.state.specificList);
    });
  };
```

```js
// console.log results
06:22:48: test:  Object {
06:22:48:   "muscleGroup": "Chest",
06:22:48:   "title": "Barbell Bench Press",
06:22:48: }
06:22:48: after each loop:  Array []
06:22:48: test:  Object {
06:22:48:   "muscleGroup": "Chest",
06:22:48:   "title": "Barbell Bench Press",
06:22:48: }
06:22:48: after each loop:  Array []
06:22:48: after each loop:  Array []

6:08:04: Object { // what innerArr the object looks like
06:08:04:   "muscleGroup": "Chest",
06:08:04:   "title": "Barbell Bench Press",
06:08:04: }
```

Answer (score 2):

Some small notes on [`.setState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) from [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous):

> React may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for performance.
>
> Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

I would simply use another object at the start of the loop (Copying from the current state), modify that variable in the loop, and then do one `.setState()` at the very end, after all your loops are done.

Answer (score 1):

Try to log the output with setState callback, like this:

```
this.setState({
    specificList: [...this.state.specificList, innerArr.title]
}, () => {
    console.log("after each loop: ", this.state.specificList);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is ***asynchronous***. That means that the value of the state values don't update immediately.

What you are doing is looping through a series of values and setting the state of `specificList` to the concatenation of the current value of `specificList` plus a single item from the array.

So if `specificList` were `['a', 'b', 'c']` and the array you're looping over were `[1, 2, 3]`, then you would essentially be calling:

```
setState({ specificList: ['a', 'b', 'c', 1] })
setState({ specificList: ['a', 'b', 'c', 2] })
setState({ specificList: ['a', 'b', 'c', 3] })
```

You can see how all of the values of the array except for the last one get left out.

One way to fix this is to pass a function to `setState` instead of a value. This will allow you to work with `setState`'s asynchronous behavior:

```
updateState = () => {
    this.props.completeList.forEach(index => {
        index.list.forEach(innerArr => {
            if (innerArr.muscleGroup === this.props.selectedBodyPart) {
                console.log("test: ", innerArr);
                this.setState(({ specificList } => ({
                  specificList: [...specificList, innerArr.title]
                }));
            }
        });
      });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to call setState once you have looped through both of you loops. For eg. you can do something like this:

```
updateState = () => {
  let temp = this.state.specificList;

  this.props.completeList.forEach(index => {
    index.list.forEach(innerArr => {
      if (innerArr.muscleGroup === this.props.selectedBodyPart) {
        console.log("test: ", innerArr);
        temp.push(innerArr.title);
      }
    });
    console.log("after each loop: ", temp)
  });

  this.setState({ specificList: temp }); 
}
```